# How do I display text in an empty field in an sql query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to pull a customer list from a database, but if the second address field is empty I want to display the text None Provided. Here is my query:

```
    select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, address, 
    address2, postal_code 
    from customer
    inner join address 
    using (address_id);
```

If address2 is blank, I want to display "none provided". How do I do that? I'm sure the answer is super simple, but I'm having a brain fart and I can't find the answer anywhere.

Ok, this is what I ended up going with:

```
    case when address2=" " or address2 is null then 'None Provided' 
    else address2 end as address2,
```

Is there a better way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no better way.  You need to compare to both values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `CASE`:

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, 
   address, 
   case when address2 is null then 'None Provided' else address2 end as address2, 
   postal_code 
from customer
inner join address 
using (address_id);
```

Or even better [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, 
   address, 
   COALESCE(address2,'None Provided') as address2, 
   postal_code 
from customer
inner join address 
using (address_id);
```

If the data contains an empty string or null, then I would consider using:

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, 
   address, 
   case 
     when address2 is null or address2 = '' 
     then 'None Provided' 
     else address2 end as address2, 
   postal_code 
from customer
inner join address 
using (address_id);
```

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using case, as I couldn't get coalesce to work.

Comment: Thanks for the info - I didn't know about accepting answers. :-)

Comment: @TaraX No problem, a lot of new users do know about it. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the built-in [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) function to achieve this.

> Returns the first non-NULL value in the list, or NULL if there are no
>   non-NULL values.

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, address, 
COALESCE(address2, 'None provided') as address2, postal_code 
from customer
inner join address 
using (address_id);
```

Comment: I've tried using both the Coalesce and IfNull functions, but nothing displays in my results, just an empty field under address2. I think that for some reason it is not recognizing the field as null, but as having a space in them. Is it possible to tell MySql something to the effect of:
If address2 = " " then "none provided"?

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, address, 
    COALESCE(address2,'none provided') as address2, postal_code 
    from customer
    inner join address 
    using (address_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

use COALESCE...

```
select concat(first_name, " ", last_name) as CustomerName, address, COALESCE(address2, 'None provided') as address2, postal_code from customer inner join address using (address_id);
```

COALESCE will return the first non-NULL value in the list