# Display message in table if cell content is empty

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to echo values from mysql database into a table but some values may be empty and I don't want the cell to output empty. Is there a way for me to show a message e.g "N/A" if a particular value is empty in the database?

```
<table><tr><td>Friends Name:</td><td><b>".$row['first_name']."&nbsp; ".$row['last_name']."</b></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Using a ternary operator on `empty()` is an option. However, if your columns have NULL values, then that is not considered as "empty".

Comment: You should do this in your SQL statement instead of in your html source. You can see an example over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15231289/how-do-i-display-text-in-an-empty-field-in-an-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Friends Name:</td>
        <?php if($row['first_name']): ?>
            <td><b>".$row['first_name']."&nbsp; ".$row['last_name']."</b></td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td><b>N/A</b></td>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```